# Turning 2D graphics into 3D in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, mplot3d

In 2D I have my x that gets the value of the x and y coordinates:

```
x = [[0.72,0.82]]
```

And at some point in the code I use this:

```
plt.plot(x[i][0], x[i][1], 'go', markersize=15, alpha=.5)
```

Now I have an x that gets the value of the x, y, and z coordinates:

```
x = [[0.72,0.82,-0.77]]
```

And I want to reproduce the same effect of 2D only now in 3D, I tried to do something like:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.set_xlim(-1, 1)
ax.set_ylim(-1, 1)
ax.set_zlim(-1, 1)
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')

ax.scatter(x[i][0], x[i][1], x[i][2], 'go', markersize=15, alpha=.5)
```

But I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: Unknown property markersize
```

P.S.: I'm using:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
```

I'd like to know how can I plot them correctly.

Comment: As far as I know `ax.scatter` has no argument `markersize`

Comment: Yes! I got it, but how do I do something like that?

Comment: You mean change the scatter points size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [matplotlib reference](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.Axes3D.scatter) for `ax.scatter` arguments, `markerzise` and `alpha` are not there, to change points' size you should use `s`argument, something like:

```
ax.scatter(xs, ys, zs, s=10, c=c, marker=m)
```

Notice `s` can also be an array of the same length as `xs` if you want points' size to be proportional to it's `xs`value.

Comment: It's work! Another thing, in 2D I use plt.clf() to clean the graph, how to do this in 3D?